# Matplotlib aligment of subplots / set vertical space (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 plots stacked on eachother. The legend of the upper graph consists of larger numbers, so the graph gets pushed to the right. I have seen that there is a concept of anchoring, but I did not manage to implement it. My idea was to align the left y-axis. Also, the space between the subplots is a bit too wide, is there a way to control that behaviour?

Could anyone help me out?

Many thanks and stay safe everyone!

I created some test data:

[image: data]

The code:

```
fig, host = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
plt.title('test')
fig, hos = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,2))

par1 = host.twinx()

p1, = host.plot(df.ExpectedValueEUR, "b-", marker = 'o', label="ExpectedValueEUR")
p2, = par1.plot(df.Count, "r-", label="Count", ls='dotted')
p3, = hos.plot(df.Average, "g-", label="Average", ls='dashed')

host.set_ylim(1000000, 20000000)
par1.set_ylim(5, 100)
hos.set_ylim(0, 1200000)

hos.set_xlabel("Date")
host.set_ylabel("ExpectedValueEUR")
par1.set_ylabel("Count")
hos.set_ylabel("Average")

host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
hos.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
par1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
hos.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
host.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

line1 = [p1, p2]
line2 = [p3]
host.legend(line1, [l.get_label() for l in line1])
hos.legend(line2, [l.get_label() for l in line2])

host.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
hos.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))

plt.show()
```

The graph looks like that:
[image: graph]

Comment: figured it out myself. one solution is to initiate both plots in "1 go".

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you mean by that?